# Non floated elements going out of parent

Tags: css, overflow

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="red">1</div>
      <div class="green">2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Styles

```
.red {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Output
[image]

When I add float left to red class, I am getting the below output.
[image]

May I know why the content of green div is overflowing outside of the parent div when I float the red div?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to understand the floating behavior.